# iPhone native app + payment gateway

Tags: iphone, payment-gateway

I want to implement payment gateway for iPhone native app.

I have read in few of the sites that I can integrate apple payment gateway for this through In App Purchase. But if I want to do through In App Purchase then, I have register each of my  product with AppStore and set a price margin for each.

Rather I am building something like shopping cart where prices of products are different.

Please guide how should I proceed, is there any other payment gateway that I can integrate with my iPhone native app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PayPal MECL library for this.
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index

From the above link download Mobile Express Checkout Library for iOS and in downloaded zip file two examples will be there one for non-web and other for web.

In non-web you have to keep the business (merchant) credentials in your application refer MECL non-web example accompanied with the library zip file.

If you don't want to keep the credentials in your application then you can handle the product selling through web service, and this is recommended way.

For more information read https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/how-to-guides/how-accept-payments-ios-app-using-mecl

Comment: this is very useful thnx :)